# post request in node app return 404 not found in cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, routes, http-post

I use the mvc routing in my node app and Whenever I post a request to the cpanel server side (route file) for processing in my node app I receive a 404 error but the route are accurate when I checked. but it works well on localhost andon cpanel when i try not to use mvc routing i.e post and receive the request in app.js.

Frontend Code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/rest",
                method: "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                     email: 'akpulufabian@gmail.com', password: '0000'
                }),
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log(data)
                }
                
            });
```

Backend Code [route file]

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const parser = bodyParser.json({ limit: '16mb'});
const { rest, index } = require('../controllers/rest');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/index', index);

router.post('/rest', parser, rest);

module.exports =  router ;
```

Backend Code [controller file]

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
require('dotenv').config();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const { ObjectId, MongoDBNamespace } = require('mongodb');
//const {dbConn} = require('../db');

let db;

const app = express();


const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60; 
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, 'news app secret', {
        expiresIn: maxAge
    });
};

const index = (req, res) => {
    res.render('rest')
}


const rest = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({ user: "test successfully carried out..." })
}

module.exports = {
    index,
    rest
};
```

Comment: All the code is above.

Comment: Can someone please help me out